# How to set up probabilities for calling functions

Tags: python, data-structures, probability

I have a list of functions like this:

```
def function1(a,b):
   ...

def function2(a,b,c,d):
   ...

def function3(a,b,c):
   ...

...and so on
```

and these functions are individually passed into this function:

```
 new_function = random_func(function2(a,b,c,d), other_parameter)
```

I want to set a logic where I can say something like: `Call function2 30% of the time`. Basically, for each function, I want to declare a probability value for how often it will be passed into `random_func()`.

**Update**

```
import random

def function1():
    print('function1')

def function2():
    print('function2')

def function3():
    print('function3')


func_args = [(function1()),(function2()),(function3())]

# Choose random function
(func, args), = random.choices(func_args, weights=[0.5, 0.3, 0.2])
#                                   probabilities ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

# Call it
result = func(*args)

print(result)
```

```
function1
function2
function3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/onur/Desktop/random_function.py", line 16, in <module>
    (func, args), = random.choices(func_args, weights=[0.5, 0.3, 0.2])
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/random.html#random.choices) to specify the probabilities:

```
func_args = [
    (function1, (a, b)),
    (function2, (a, b, c, d)),
    (function3, (a, b, c))
]

# Choose random function
(func, args), = random.choices(func_args, weights=[0.5, 0.3, 0.2])
#                                   probabilities ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

# Call it
result = func(*args)
```

Comment: But what this does is create a new list that has the same function repeating. Can't I create  dice logic like `dice = random.randint(1,100)`?

Comment: @oo92, `random.choices` is the dice logic. `(func, args),` extracts the only element of the list, so `func` is a function and `args` is a tuple of its arguments.

Comment: Your code throws `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: @oo92, [It doesn't?](https://tio.run/##hY/BasMwDIbvegrRXewhTJtsl0EPo49R2pE4TmNIo2A7jFL67JndhmxhjOmgg75f@n/1l9Bwl4@jPffsArqiq/gMUJka66HTwXK3EQWV8g0QUSm1ZFlipKn6g@cP/oNOetzihjLK6QWS9qNwJx9n@6RDMVsTxgNYSklLkE2AUBNWv3D@jaWEA8AT7hpmb6YH53xwXyFM9pJigAdXumGrjRdzNsJPY09N8Nv9Wr0SrlWeWnaQ8fb/1Tsui9K2Nljj8bgsgN7ZLoh69V7yEDAw6qJt8Zrcb9dkf1sln12a2gDO@KENMW0SiOd7@HH8Ag "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Check the edit on the post to see my implementation

Comment: @oo92, well, `(function1())` is not a tuple - it's the value of the function call, which is `None`. Thus, `random.choices` will definitely return `[None]`, which `(func, args),` will attempt to unpack, but it's not possible to unpack `None`.

Comment: So how should I fix my implementation of your logic?

Comment: @oo92, `func_args = [(function1, ()), (function2, ()), (function3, ())]`

Comment: Can you explain the `result = func(*args)` syntax?

Comment: This code throws `TypeError: function4() argument after * must be an iterable, not int` if there is only 1 parameter

Comment: @oo92, that one parameter must be written as `(1,)`, not `(1)`. My solution relies on the fact that functions are objects too, so you can pass functions around without calling them. I want to randomly choose a function and its corresponding arguments, so I put a function and a _tuple_ of its arguments (without evaluating the function!) in a tuple. `func_args` is a list of such tuples. Once a function has been chosen, I use iterable unpacking to pass these arguments to the function: `func(*args)` is the same as `func(args[0], args[1], ..., args[-1])`.

Comment: I solved the one-parameter problem by writing them all as [a,b,c,d] lists.